# who/when the package was installed in debian

Tags: debian, apt

Any way to find out who installs the package and when the package was installed in debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who, I think it should be root, but when, check /var/log/dpkg.log. You will have the dates of install, update, delete of all the packages.

Comment: "who" is effectively root, yes, but that is only half of the answer since the chances of one of your users being named "root smith" are pretty remote. Depending on your configuration you may be able to leverage your sudo log to see which user(s) are elevating their privileges and, again depending on configuration, which package(s) they have installed. Obviously with physical access and the root password there is very little forensic data that can be recovered to trace actions back to a single human.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in: `/var/log/apt/history.log` for when. As for who, you need to be root to install packages, so it'll always be root. (If you use sudo, you might want to configure sudo to log when someone uses any of the relevant commands (dpkg/aptitude/apt-get etc...)

Comment: /var/log/apt/history.log don't exists on my Lenny, but it is available on Squeeze.

Comment: I found it in /var/log/apt/term.log instead. thanks!